# Clear cache for wildcard page

Tags: publishing, caching, wildcards

How would I approach clearing the cache in the scenario where I have a wildcard page in my site

e.g. `/sitecore/content/MySite/Home/Products/*` which references another section of the content tree such as

`/sitecore/content/MySite/Data/ProductCatalog/`

Say I change a product under /Data/ProductCatalog and publish, how can I ensure that the cache is cleared for the correct page/URL?

Comment: Which cache do you want to clear?

Comment: When you publish *any* item, the **entire** HMTML cache is cleared. You do not need to do anything to target specific pages or items.

Comment: @RichardSeal I want to clear the HTML cache.

Comment: @jammykam can't believe I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [@jammykam](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/135/jammykam)'s comment, when you publish *any* item, the **entire** HTML cache is cleared. You do not need to do anything to target specific pages or items.

*What you do need to do, is ensure you are not publishing items too often otherwise your site will be clearing its HTML cache all the time!*